# AngularJS: Cookie get deleted on login page while authentication

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-router

I am using ngCookie -> $cookieStore for authentication. Its working fine in mozilla, but its not working proper in chrome and ie.

The problem in chrome and ie is when anyone login the user will be redirected to dashboard. but at the same moment, if anyone access login page the cookie is not showing

See screenshot for the same[image][image]

Comment: What is your domain value of cookie being set? Are you facing this problem locally?

Comment: I am facing locally as well as on linux server

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem for localhost servers and if you are setting your domain value to **localhost** in your cookie, then it must be a bug or implementation problem from Chrome i.e. Chrome browser doesn't allow cookies to set domain for localhost domains.

See the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

Hope this helps!

Comment: But i am facing the same problem on LINUX server as well which shows ip address in domain.

Comment: Let me access using DNS. Get back to you soon. :)

Comment: If you do not have your domain name then you can probably remove the domain value from cookie untill you get the domain name and for development purpose also.